# The Recycle Bin on C:\ Is Corrupt or Invalid

Tags: windows-xp, corruption, windows

I have a user running xp sp2 that keeps getting "The Recycle Bin on C:\ Is Corrupt or Invalid." kb297760 says that this can be caused if the subst command is used to map a drive to an existing folder. Some software they use actually does do this (DocumentFX from CCH) and MS provides a hotfix, however this fix is for sp1... I have also tried logging in as admin and resetting NTFS rights on c:\RECYCLER to the defaults with no luck. I would like to avoid upgrading to sp3 if possible - not sure that will even fix the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't have the error from 297760 if you're running SP2.  Could this [Compaq knowledge base article](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00029389&lc=en&dlc=&cc=us&lang=&rule=5513&product=92321) help?

(It says to remove c:\recycled but it may actually mean c:\recycler).

Comment: yes, it is the recycler folder that is corrupt.

Comment: I will try the KB from compaq and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: In XP simply deleting c:\recycler via command line (rd /s c:\recycler) and rebooting fixed it. It will probably happen again unless I upgrade to SP3 but the PC is slated to be replaced next week...

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to SP3. Its been fixed. Its not feasible or reasonable to get every patch in any order you want them in.

Comment: The program is documentfx by CCH. Uses the subst command to map to a deeply nested folder. MS says that subst can cause this reycle bin corruption as stated in kb297760

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this reg file (there seems to be no way to attach a file so here's the entries):

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}]
@="Recycle Bin"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}]
@="Recycle Bin"
"InfoTip"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,53,00,48,00,45,00,4c,00,4c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,\
  2d,00,32,00,32,00,39,00,31,00,35,00,00,00
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000060
"IntroText"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,53,00,48,00,45,00,4c,00,4c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,\
  2d,00,33,00,31,00,37,00,34,00,38,00,00,00
"LocalizedString"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,\
  6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,48,00,45,00,4c,00,4c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,38,00,39,00,36,00,34,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
  65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,33,00,31,00,00,\
  00
"Empty"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,\
  68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,33,00,31,\
  00,00,00
"Full"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,\
  68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,33,00,32,\
  00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\InProcServer32]
@="shell32.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\shellex]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\ShellFolder]
"Attributes"=hex:40,01,00,20
"CallForAttributes"=dword:00000040

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this on a Win2008 terminal server and it was due to a corrupted profile. Deleting the profile and getting the user to log back in fixed it.

Back up the users Desktop, Favorites and My Documents first, or you won't be popular. I speak from experience :-)

JR